# Qt WIdget inside ToolTip

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, c++11, qt5.3

Is it, maybe by using some dirty hakish stuff, possible to use a `QWidget` as a tooltip or archive a similar mechanic?
I want to have such a thing, because I have a list of some participants for a contest and would like to use a `QListView` for displaying everyone inside that contest when I hover the total participant count. I'm using `Qt5.3`.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kwidgetsaddons/html/classKToolTipWidget.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `QToolTip` can contain and display rich text, so you could create a the look of a table by using the HTML tags that are supported (see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html)).

If that does not suffice for your case, then you could always create your custom widget and display it at the right time by listening to the right events: [`QEvent::ToolTip`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html) would seem the right one.
Overriding `QWidget::event(QEvent *)` would give you something like:

```
bool MyWidget::event(QEvent * event) override
{
    if ( event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip )
    {
        myToolTip_->show();
    }
}
```

But then you'd need to place your tooltip widget at the correct position, take care of hiding it when not needed anymore and so on... So I'd try the rich text version first.