# [Qt][C++] setMinimumWidth and setMaximumWidth not working on label

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have label created and want tooltip over it, I want to set tooltip's maximum and minimum width but somehow its not working.
I am not expert to QT, not able to figure out the reason.

Code:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QListWidgetItem>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QListWidget listWidget;
    listWidget.setContentsMargins(QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0));


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem();
        auto *itemWidget = new QWidget();
        auto *textLabel = new QLabel(QString("Item %1").arg(i + 1), itemWidget);
        textLabel->setMinimumWidth(100); //Not working whatever value I set
        textLabel->setMaximumWidth(400); //Not working whatever value I set
        textLabel->setToolTip("<p>This is the looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonggggggggggggggg name </p>");

        listWidget.addItem(item);
        listWidget.setItemWidget(item, itemWidget);
    }

    listWidget.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Tooltip:

[image]

**can someone please help.**

Answer (score 1):

You cant directly set max and min on tooltip , hence you should indrectly do that(for this usecase):

```cpp
static const QString FORMATTER = "<p>%1</p>";
QString tooltip =
    "This is the "
    "looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo"
    "oooooooooooooooooonggggggggggggggg name.";
static constexpr auto maximum = 10;
textLabel->setToolTip(FORMATTER.arg(tooltip.mid(0, maximum)));
```

**Update:**

if you want exactly have  your widget with any properties for tooltip , you can override your events and show the ToolTipWidget that reimplemented.
i.e: [Qt WIdget inside ToolTip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328957/qt-widget-inside-tooltip)

Comment: This will also crop the tooltip text

Comment: @KrishnaPadia ofc your right , and what doing minimum width? cropping text too width extra padding text , in this situation you can add "..." too.

Answer (score 0):

```
textLabel->setMinimumWidth(100);
textLabel->setMaximumWidth(400);
```

This will set the min/max width of the label itself not the tooltip.

If you want to customize tooltip behavior, you'll have to override the [event()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#event) function to catch `QEvent::ToolTip` (and probably `QEvent::ToolTipChange`) and draw it yourself using [QToolTip::showText()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtooltip.html#showText)

Answer (score -1):

please use :textLabel->setToolTip